# Updating a modified Prestashop

Tags: centos, console, diff

I don't know if this is the proper forum for this; didn't really seem like a Stack Overflow question, so if I'm in the wrong here, do point me to the correct SE site.

Anyway, I have a Prestashop 1.4.7.3 installed on a CentOS 5 machine. Recently, they released the 1.5.0 version, which I'd like to upgrade to.

However, during developing a rather customized theme for it, I had to modify the core files (and yes I know how stupid this was, and probably even more stupid that I didn't keep a list of modified files). What's done is done though.

So now I'm faced with a problem; I need to update, but I don't want it to overwrite my modifications.

Is there a way (preferably in the console) to do a diff between my current installation and 1.4.7.3 vanilla, to get a list of files that are modified (sans the themes folder, perhaps)?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the "vanilla" version and the modified version are in 2 different directories, A command like the following should show the differences.

`rsync -ahPn /path/to/modified/version/ /path/to/vanilla/version/`
(this just tests sizes and timestamps)

`rsync -ahPcn /path/to/modified/version/ /path/to/vanilla/version/`  (This will additionally do hash checks on the files, which could take a while)

Remember the trailing slashes.  Rsync is finicky about that.